# UIImageView coordinate to subview coordinates

Tags: iphone, graphics, uiimageview

If I start with a UIImageView, and I add a subview, how do I translate a coordinate in the original UIImageView to a corresponding coordinate (the same place on the screen) in the subview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UIView provides methods for exactly this purpose. In your case you have two options:

```
CGPoint newLocation = [imageView convertPoint:thePoint toView:subview];
```

or

```
CGPoint newLocation = [subview convertPoint:thePoint fromView:imageView];
```

They both do the same thing, so pick whichever one feels more appropriate. There's also equivalent functions for converting rects. These functions will convert between any two views on the same window. If the destination view is nil, it converts to/from the window base coordinates. These functions can handle views that aren't direct descendants of each other, and it can also handle views with transforms (though the rect methods may not produce accurate results in the case of a transform that contains any rotation or skewing).

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Ballard.  This looks like a much nicer answer than mine.  I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the subview's frame.origin from the point in the parents view to the same point in the subview's coordinate:

subviewX = parentX - subview.frame.origin.x;

subviewY = parentY - subview.frame.origin.y;

Comment: Sorry @jamihash, I had worked this out and wanted to put it up, so asked myself a question.  Your answer implies that  subview.frame.origin.x=subViewWidth/2-subViewCenterX, which doesn't sound silly to me.  If it works, I really like it as working with centers all the time can be confusing.

Comment: This doesn't take transforms into account.

Comment: OK, so if the view has been reflected and/or scaled etc. using .transform, this would be inaccurate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with code like:

```
UIImageView* superView=....;
UIImageView subView=[
    [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,subViewWidth,subViewHeight)
];
subView.center=CGPointMake(subViewCenterX, subViewCenterY);
[superView addSubview:subView];
```

The `(subViewCenterX, subViewCenterY)` coordinate is a point, in superView, where the center of `subView` is "pinned".  The subView can be moved around wrt the superView by moving its center around.  We can go, for example

```
subView.center=CGPointMake(subViewCenterX+1, subViewCenterY);
```

to move it 1 point to the right.  Now lets say we have a point `(X,Y)` in the superView, and we want to find the corresponding point `(x,y)` in the subView, so that `(X,Y)` and `(x,y)` refer to the same point on the screen.  The formula for x is:

```
x=X+subViewWidth/2-subViewCenterX;
```

and similarly for y:

```
y=Y+subViewHeight/2-subViewCenterY;
```

To explain this, if you draw a box representing the superView, and another (larger) box representing the subView, the difference `subViewWidth/2-subViewCenterX` is "the width of the bit of the subView box sticking out to the left of the superView"

Comment: Besides being confusing, this doesn't take transforms into account.